# I have a problem in font rendering in linux terminal

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, fonts

I am using this font named laconic on my linux terminal. I am facing two problems here. The first problem is that there is a big space between my `username@machine` and command input area.

[image]

Secondly when I select any text with cursor it is selecting at another text by using some space area. I have googled a lot about this issue but not found anything useful. If anyone have some idea on how to fix this, then it would be higly appreciated. I love this font but due to this problem I am not able to use it.

Comment: Terminals need a fixed width (a.k.a. monospace) font, which this one apparently isn't.